# Which type of Xbox console should I get to begin developing games on it?

Tags: xna, xbox

If I want to start developing small indie-like games with XNA on Xbox (I don't think any game I'd make would need more than 100, maybe 200 megabytes), will the 4gb Slim (I want to get a slim version because of the wi-fi) version of the console be enough, or should I get the 250 gb version? I don't really plan to play actively on the console as I'm more interested in developing on it. Also, will a console and a verified student XBLIG account be enough to set up everything I need to run and debug my game on the console?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

You'll need an actual hard-drive to use the XNA connect application (upload your game) - but not to play other games.

You'll need a physical hard-drive - NOT flash memory to deploy games.

If you have a AppHub Membership (from DreamSpark, you say yours is from); this is all you need. You will link it with your Gamertag and download the Connect App and and you'll be all set from there.

Comment: You actually need a hard drive to develop with XNA on the 360. You can download and play XBLIG with just the built-in 4GB drive but the XNA connect application that allows you to deploy your own games to the Xbox requires a hard drive. See http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/74847/571243.aspx

Comment: Corrected - odd this isn't actually documented anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I would buy the 250gb version (which as I read comes with an actual hard drive), I'd be all set up and I won't have to buy a seperate hard drive, right? Just for clarification :-)

Comment: Yeah, you need at least a 250GB model at that case (if you must get a Slim for WiFi) this is your only feasible choice.